# android app with it's robotium test code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, robotium

Where can I find an android app code with its robotium test code online?

I'm looking for something really simple that can just display written content when pressing a button or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can download an app and example test project from here:

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started